# Assembly program, which enters from keyboard arbitrary alphanumeric sequence until pressing “ESC”

Tags: assembly, reverse

Have to make an Assembly program, which enters from keyboard arbitrary alphanumeric sequence until pressing "ESC" and prints inserted sequence in reverse order, but without numbers.

example: "Acd1fop67klm2xwz" -> "zwxmlkpofdcA"

I made this by now:

```
MAX     EQU     20
BUF     DB      MAX DUP(?)    

SUB AH,AH
       INT 16H
       CMP AH,1
       JE  ;end of entering

 MOV BX,OFFSET BUF
       SUB DI,DI  


GETCH:  ...
       MOV [BX+DI],AL
       INC DI
       CMP DI,MAX
       JNE GETCH        

PREV:   DEC DI
       JS  KRAI
       MOV AL,[BX+DI]
       CMP AL,30H
       JB  NODIG
       CMP AL,39H
       JBE PREV
NODIG:; show symbols
       JMP PREV
KRAI:  ;ends the program
```

Comment: What processor are you programming?

Comment: for the .x86 processor

Comment: So what is your question..? I mean, the code doesn't look like it would assemble, but what specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: My question is how to get make working this code, to run the functions: by pressing "ESC" prints inserted sequence in reverse order, but without numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've got your buffer where the CPU will try to execute it. You probably want that in a separate data segment (initialize `ds`!)... or put it at the end.

When you get to `jne getch`, you probably want to go all the way back to where you actually get another character from the keyboard. But you initialize `bx` and `di` after that. You probably want to do that before your main input loop.

When you get to the "show symbols" label, you probably want to actually do that. `int 29h` is a quick-and-dirty way to print the character in `al` with no side effects. It's documented as "for internal use", so you may want to use another method (`int 29h` can't be redirected to another file).

When you get to the end (`KRAI:`), you actually need to exit. "Exit" is something every program needs to do, so you probably should learn to do that first!

In general, you're on the right track - keep working on it. Your logic to skip digits looks okay to me, and kudos for not reinventing `gets()`! A debugger may help, but once you've got it outputting something, you can probably see what's wrong (if anything).